# Vue should send mail only if recaptcha is solved and user checked checkbox

Tags: javascript, vue.js, recaptcha

I'm creating SPA based on VueJs. I would like to add simple if state. If user check checkbox and recaptcha is solved corectly, Vue sent mail. It is working. But if checkbox wasn't checked before click "Send button", user can't sent mail anymore until reloading page even if user checked box as he was asked about.

I tried making if statements and switch. Probably problem is with Vue Recaptcha or fact that it is method.

```
    <template>
        <b-row>
        <b-col cols=12 xl=6>
          <h2 class="display-1">Contact Form</h2>
          <label>Name</label>
          <div class="form-group">
          <b-form-input v-model="user_name" placeholder="Provide name"></b-form-input>
          <label class="pt-3">Mail</label>
          <b-form-input v-model="user_reply" placeholder="Provide mail"></b-form-input>
          <label class="pt-3">Message</label>
          <textarea v-model="user_message" rows="3" placeholder="message" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <b-form-checkbox
              id="checkbox-1"
              v-model="selected"
              name="checkbox-1"
              value="true"
              unchecked-value="false"
        >
         I accept <router-link class="text-white" to="/privacy"><b>the privacy policy</b></router-link>
        </b-form-checkbox>
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols=6 xl=3 class="pt-3">
              <vue-recaptcha
              ref="recaptcha"
              @verify="onVerify"
              @expired="onExpired"
              :sitekey="sitekey">
               <button class="btn-primary">Sent message</button>
          </vue-recaptcha>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
      {{selected}}
          <p v-if="message_status == 'error'" class="text-danger">Error during sending</p>
          <p v-if="message_status == 'success'" class="text-success">Message was send correctly</p>
          <p v-if="message_status == 'error_check'" class="text-danger">You have to accept privacy.</p>

        </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </template>

    <script>
    import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';

    export default {
      name: 'contact',
      components: { VueRecaptcha },
      data() {
        return{
          sitekey: 'RECAPTCHA KEY HERE',
          user_name: '',
          user_reply: '',
          user_message: '',
          message_status: '',
          selected: 'false',
        }
      },
      methods: {
        sendMail() {
          var service_id = 'gmail';
          var template_id = 'template_ZZsyPIab';
          var template_params = {
              to_name: this.user_name,
              from_name: this.user_reply,
            message_html: this.user_message
            };
          emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params);
        },
        onSubmit() {
               this.$refs.invisibleRecaptcha.execute();
        },
        onVerify(response) {
          console.log('Verify: ' + response)
          switch (this.selected) {
              case 'true':
                  var service_id = 'gmail';
                  var template_id = 'template_ZZsyPIab';
                  var template_params = {
                    to_name: this.user_name,
                    from_name: this.user_reply,
                    message_html: this.user_message
                    };
                    emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params)
                      .then(() => {
                        this.message_status = 'success';
                      }, function(err) {
                      this.message_status = 'error';
                    });
                break;
              case 'false':
                this.message_status = 'error_check';
                break;
              default:
                this.message_status = 'error_check';
            }

        },
        onExpired: function () {
          console.log('Expired')
        },
      },
    }
    </script>

    <style lang="scss" scoped>
    ...
    </style>
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Maybe it will be useful for somebody in future.

```
    <template>
    <b-row>
    <b-col cols=12 xl=6>
          <h2 class="display-1">Formularz Kontaktowy</h2>
          <label>Twoje imię:</label>
          <div class="form-group">
          <b-form-input v-model="user_name" placeholder="Podaj swoje imię"></b-form-input>
          <label class="pt-3">Twój e-mail:</label>
          <b-form-input v-model="user_reply" placeholder="Podaj mail"></b-form-input>
          <label class="pt-3">Śmiało napisz co Ci leży na duszy.</label>
          <textarea v-model="user_message" rows="3" placeholder="Wiadomość" class="form-control"></textarea>
          </div>
          <b-form-checkbox
              id="checkbox-1"
              v-model="selected"
              name="checkbox-1"
              value="true"
              unchecked-value="false"
        >
         Akceptuję <router-link class="text-white" to="/privacy"><b>Politykę prywatności</b></router-link>
        </b-form-checkbox>
          <b-row>
            <b-col cols=6 xl=3 class="pt-3">
              <vue-recaptcha
              ref="recaptcha"
              @verify="onVerify"
              @expired="onExpired"
              :sitekey="sitekey">
               <button v-on:click="sendMail" class="btn-primary">Wyślij</button>
          </vue-recaptcha>
            </b-col>
          </b-row>
          <p v-if="message_status == 'error'" class="text-danger">Wystąpił błąd w trakcie wysyłania.</p>
          <p v-if="message_status == 'success'" class="text-success">Wiadomość została wysłana prawidłowo</p>
          <p v-if="message_status == 'error_check'" class="text-danger">Musisz zaakceptować politykę prywatności.</p>
        {{recaptchaWork}}
        </b-col>
        </b-row>
    </template>

    <script>
    import VueRecaptcha from 'vue-recaptcha';

    export default {
      name: 'contact',
      components: { VueRecaptcha },
      data() {
        return{
          sitekey: 'SITEKEY RECAPTCHA',
          user_name: '',
          user_reply: '',
          user_message: '',
          message_status: '',
          selected: 'false',
          recaptchaWork: 'false',
        }
      },
      methods: {
         sendMail(){
          if (this.selected == 'false') {
            this.message_status = 'error_check';
          }
          if (this.recaptchaWork == 'true' && this.selected == 'true') {
              var service_id = 'gmail';
                  var template_id = 'template_ZZsyPIab';
                  var template_params = {
                    to_name: this.user_name,
                    from_name: this.user_reply,
                    message_html: this.user_message
                    };
                    emailjs.send(service_id,template_id,template_params)
                      .then(() => {
                        this.message_status = 'success';
                      }, function(err) {
                      this.message_status = 'error';
                    });
          }
        },
        onSubmit() {
               this.$refs.invisibleRecaptcha.execute();
        },
        onVerify(response) {
          console.log('Verify: ' + response)
          console.log(this.selected)
          this.recaptchaWork = 'true';
        },
        onExpired: function () {
          console.log('Expired')
        },
        resetRecaptcha () {
          this.$refs.recaptcha.reset() // Direct call reset method
        }
      },
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: It would be great to an explainer about how you solved it rather than just dump code